# Can Chrome extensions send messages to other users' browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, keypress

I'm looking for a way to do some key control with a Chrome extension -- let's say that Alice and Bob both have Extension C installed on Chrome. Is there a way for Alice to send a keypress event to Bob through the extension?

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external This article *almost* covers this use case, but it seems not to be about communicating between two instances of the same extension, more about between two different extensions.

Comment: You are better off creating a server to take data from client and broadcast it where ever it needs to go

Comment: There is no such API for extensions. The external messaging is nowhere near "almost" covering the need.